# Angular JS routing is not working on below code. URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

** --Routing is not working on Angular JS . Please help. HTML code and js file attached. --**
  **Below is my HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Routing Examples</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <ul class="nav"> 
                    <li>
                        <a href="#AddNewOrder">Add New Order</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#ShowOrder">Show Orders</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div ng-view>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


/// <reference path="C:\Dev\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Scripts/angular.js" />
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
//Define Routing 
sampleApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/AddNewOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/AddNewOrder.html',
        controller: 'AddOrderController'
    }).when('/ShowOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/ShowOrder.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrderController'
    });
});

sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "This is Add Order screen";
});

sampleApp.controller('ShowOrderController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "This is show Order screen";
});
```

Wrong URL is getting populated on browser addressbar when clicking on the AddNew Order link.
http://localhost:63022/Sample1.html#!#AddNewOrder

*Please suggest what is wrong here.. Routing is not working at all.*

Comment: Please help here.. i am not able find why this routing is not working.

Comment: Don't prefix your `href` attributes with `#`. See the example here ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Comment: try ui-sref in place of href

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal OP is using `ngRoute`, not `ui.router`

Answer (score 1):

Your links are wrong.
Try this:

```
            <li>
                <a href="#/AddNewOrder">Add New Order</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/ShowOrder">Show Orders</a>
            </li>
```

Or without #/ at all

Comment: <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <ul class="nav"> 
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/AddNewOrder">Add New Order</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/ShowOrder">Show Orders</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div ng-view>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: So it worked? Don't forget to flag the answer as correct if it did.

Comment: @Hemant try without the `#/` prefix as shown in the [example in the official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example)

Comment: Right, try it like I mentioned above (or without #/)
<a href="AddNewOrder">Add New Order</a>

Comment: Also @Hermant, to make sure the routing is good, you can try changing the url manually to the expected url and checking if that works:
http://localhost:63022/#/AddNewOrder